# UTF8 with db issue

Tags: php, mysql

[image: Problem]

this title is connected to a database that is in UTF-8 Swedish-ci

php:

```
$ultimo = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM videos ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3") or die (mysql_error());
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($ultimo, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
                    $title = $row['titulo'];
                    $url = $row['url'];
                    echo '<a href="HREF DB">'.$title.'</a></p>';
                    echo '<iframe width="240" height="155" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$url.'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
                    echo '</div>';
                }
```

the problem is on the image, I want to be able to use characters like:

ç / à / á / ' / etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try executing something like this before your query:

```
mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8');
mysql_query('SET names=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_client=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_connection=utf8');
```

More about [character sets and collations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html).

To be sure that browser understands characters add a meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

One good post from SO about [UTF-8 character set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through).

Please note that mysql_* functions are deprecated and you should switch them with mysqli_*

Answer (score 1):

Language of UTF-8 in database should not matter when all pages use same database (at least in PHP).

**Are you sure that your page is UTF-8?**

1. Edit file in some good text editor like Notepad++ and check if .php file format is 'UTF-8 (without BOM)' [all PHP files of your site].
2. Did you notify web browser that your page is UTF-8 encoded? In page <head> part should be something like:

   <meta charset="UTF-8">